# Key existence checking utility in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm using the following code for checking if a key exists in a `Map` instance:

```
if (!map_instance.containsKey(key))
    throw new RuntimeException("Specified key doesn't exist in map");
else
   return map_instance.get(key);
```

My question is:

Is there a utility or `Map` implementation to simplify the above code, such as:

```
custom_map.get(key,"Specified key doesn't exist in map");
```

My goal is: if `key` does not exist in map, the map implementation throws an exception with the passed string.

I don't know whether or not my desire is reasonable?

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am still learning the English language.)

Comment: Little hint to your code: `return true;` in your else block instead of `return map_instance.containsKey(key);`, another invocation of that method is redundant (if this code is used only by one thread at a time)

Comment: @Pshemo OP in fact wants to implement `get` this way, so just the name of the method called is wrong.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are probably right, but just in case I will leave that comment so OP can notice that there is something to improve there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a look into the configuration map from Apache commons. It doesn't implements `Map`, but has a similar interface with a few Helper methods, like `getString`, `getStringArray`, `getShort` and so on.

With this implementation you could use the method `setThrowExceptionOnMissing(boolean throwExceptionOnMissing)` and could catch it and handle as you want.

Isn't exactly with a configurable message but from my point of view it doesn't make sense to throw a fixed exception just with a custom message since the exception type itself depends on the context where the `get` method is invoked. For example, if you perform a get of an user the exception would be something related to that, maybe `UserNotFoundException`, and not just a `RuntimeException` with the message: User not Found in Map!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you show a sample?I don't familiar with `Apache Common Configuration`.

Comment: `MapConfiguration mc = new MapConfiguration(properties); mc.setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true); mc.getString("key");` if key doesn't exists a `NoSuchElementExcpetion` will be thrown

Answer (score 63):

I use Optional Java util class, e.g.

```
Optional.ofNullable(elementMap.get("not valid key"))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ElementNotFoundException("Element not found"));
```

Comment: I think that's the best solution. But better use `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Good proposal, but it doesn't work when the map has an entry with null as a key on the map.as it would throw the exception rather than returning the associated value.

Comment: This totally works, however, it's an abuse of the `Optional` data type per its author: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555

Optional is to be used as a return type, not as a way to branch through chaining in operational code.

Answer (score 32):

There is one more nice way to achieve this:

```
return Objects.requireNonNull(map_instance.get(key), "Specified key doesn't exist in map");
```

Pros:

- pure Java - no libs
- no redundant Optional - less garbage

Cons:

- only `NullPointerException` - sometimes `NoSuchElementException` or custom exceptions are more desirable

Java 8 required

Answer (score 20):

In Java 8 you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) from `Map`, like this:

```
map.computeIfAbsent("invalid", key -> { throw new RuntimeException(key + " not found"); });
```

Comment: Don’t do this. "computeIfAbsent" is meant as a mutation operation. So if your map happens to be an UnmodifiableMap, or a Guava or Eclipse Collection ImmutableMap, or a ProtoMap, this call will immediately fail with some sort of UnsupportedOperationException.

A Java8 equivalent could be:
`Optional.fromNullable(map.get("invalid")).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(key + " not found"));`
This has slightly more bloat, but has the advantage of correctness.

Comment: Great comment. But the proposed alternative doesn't work when there is an entry with null as a key on the map, as it would throw the exception rather than returning the associated value.

Answer (score 2):

Such a method does not exist for a Map in Java. You could create it by extending the Map class of course or by creating a wrapper class that contains the map and a `tryGet` method.

C# however does have a such a method: `Directory.TryGetValue()`

```
public class MyMap {
    public Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    public Object tryGet(Object key, String msg) {
        if(!map.containsKey(key))
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
        return map.get(key); 
   }
```

Comment: composition over inheritance, imo.

Comment: The unfortunate side of composition is the disgusting amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing it is the way to go.

as a side note, your code doesn't make much sense since you will always return true, maybe you meant:

```
return map_instance.get(key);
```

Comment: yes, my means is `get` method invoking, I edited my question.