# Java 8 Optional<T> get

Tags: java, exception, java-8, option-type

Java 8 Optional method get throws an exception when does not exists the element.
Why does throws exception instead of return null or an Optional empty?

Comment: What is an _empty value_?

Comment: That's the whole point of Optional: to force you to handle the case when there is no value appropriately. Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-java8-optional

Comment: "static <T> Optional<T> empty()
Returns an empty Optional instance."
Thanks, @assylias

Comment: So you want an empty `Optional` to return another empty `Optional`?

Comment: This is the _entire point_, that it doesn't return `null`.

Comment: I am not sure the downvoting is entirely justified here. Maybe the phrasing of the question is not quite adequate, especially in the alternative options proposed for the Optional.get, but I can see why the OP is confused with regards to the method throwing an Exception. In fact Brian Goetz himself [acknowledges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555) that this was not a totally fortunate decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.orElse(null)` if you want null. The idea of `Optional` is to force you to *explicitly* handle the absence of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can you **Optional.orElse(null)** if you need null or the value

```
Optional optional  = Optional.empty();
System.out.println(optional.orElse(null));
```

If there is some operation or action you want to perform you an use **OptionalifPresent(Consumer operationToPerform)**

```
optional.ifPresent(o->{ // operation to perform
System.out.println(o); });
```