# Capturing ONLY sent fields in the Request body in Spring Boot PATCH rest API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a PATCH API as follows:

```
    @PatchMapping("/student)
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> patchStudent(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO)
            throws URISyntaxException {
            ...
    }
```

Here StudentDTO is as follows:

```
class StudentDTO {
   String name,
   String rollNum,
   String grade,
   String id,
  ...
```

}

Here in PATCH API, user may send any number of fields including `id` as follows:

```
Request 1:

{
  id: 1,
  name: "Test"
}

Request 2:

{
  id:1,
  name: "Test",
  rollNumber : "123456"
}

Request 3:

{
  id:1,
  name: "Test",
  rollNumber : "123456",
  grade : null.   //NOTE: user may send null as well for a field in request body
}
```

I a not getting how should I capture only those fields in the request body while patching the data in the backend?

Comment: What is the  impact of  `null` then ? `null` is also a valid value

Comment: Yeah @Eklavya, I mean someone may want to deliberately nullify one field.

Comment: @Joy I believe you can choose among a list of alternative solutions provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424383/how-to-distinguish-between-null-and-not-provided-values-for-partial-updates-in-s