# Why isn't optional used for instance variables?

Tags: java, scala, option-type

I've been reading up a lot about the cases where `Optional` should be used.

A lot of the pages I've read say that `Optional` shouldn't be used for private instance variables and instead should be returned by getters.

I would have thought that having private instance variables as optional would still be useful. If anybody looks at my code they can see that a value can be empty, instead of having to check the documentation to see if null could be returned.

In Scala null is never used and is only really there for interoperability with Java. It is recommended to always use an optional if a value can be null. This approach makes a lot more sense to me.

Here's a page mentioning it:

https://blog.joda.org/2015/08/java-se-8-optional-pragmatic-approach.html

Here is the example code.

```
private final String addressLine;  // never null
private final String city;         // never null
private final String postcode;     // optional, thus may be null

// normal getters
public String getAddressLine() { return addressLine; }
public String getCity() { return city; }

// special getter for optional field
public Optional<String> getPostcode() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(postcode);
}
```

The only advantage I can see is that if you want to serialize the object it is now possible as it isn't storing optional in a variable.

The disadvantage is that you don't know postcode could be null until you check the return type of the getter. If you were new to the code you might miss this add extend the class, causing a null pointer exception.

Here is a question asked about Scala's `Option`.

[When to use Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698391/when-to-use-option)

Why is there a difference between Java and Scala with how optional should be used?

Comment: While I don’t know Scala practice, I haven’t really seen a Java example where using an `Optional` for an instance variable buys you anything in the end. It may be convenient for some methods reading the value of the nullable variable, but just moves the burden to those methods setting it, according to my experience. That said, I have seen code with an `Optional` instance variable work without problems (I just wouldn’t have written it in the first place).

Comment: The main advantage I see from using it is that it is very clear to somebody new to the code that something could be empty/null. It also makes you think more about what should happen if the variable is empty as sometimes people forget a variable can be null. This is the approach taken in Scala anyway. In the example code you wouldn't know the variable could be null until you check what the getter returns.

Comment: A comment? A Javadoc comment? A `@Nullable` annotation? Of course it should be made clear *somehow* to new readers of the code when a variable is allowed to be null.

Comment: The very important difference is, that `Optional` is not serializable, so if you created any class with field with `Optional` you won't be able to serialize it. `Option` from Scala is serializable and as you noticed it's common practice to create `Option` fields. As I side note I need to mention, that `Option` from **Vavr** is serializable, so if you want to create fields with `Option` *scala-style* just use **Vavr**.

Comment: IMO it's mostly a matter of encapsulation. When you declare a method as returning `Optional`, it's to make it obvious that there might be an empty result without looking into code or even documentation. If you're looking at a member variable, you're _already looking at the code_.

Comment: There is no reason to use `Optional` as instance fields in java, as it does not give you anything, but in other languages, such as Rust, `Option` is tightly integrated in the language and it's not possible to do (safely) a lot of operations without it.

Comment: Java `Optional` wasn't designed to be used for member variables. There are a number of issues - for example it should have implemented `Serializable` if it was intended to be used for member variables. See: https://dzone.com/articles/optional-anti-patterns and: http://dolszewski.com/java/java-8-optional-use-cases/ It was a deliberate design choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not all Java developers even agree with the approach you described. Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674917/1303324) by the creator of Lombok.

I guess that the reason for a different approach of using `Optional` in Java is that Java's community lived without it up till Java 8, so most people were used to **null**. In one hand a lot of new APIs (like `findAny` from `Stream`) return `Optional`, but still a lot of standard library methods just return **null**, so you always have to remember either to wrap your function calls with `Optional.ofNullable` or check if the value is not null.

`Optional` was added to Java 8 but it is discouraged to use it as class fields because `Optional` is not implementing `Serializable` (and Java's serialization is used as the default serialization engine by many frameworks or systems like Akka, Spark, Kafka, etc.).

On the other hand `Option` is very tightly bound with the Scala standard library. 
As far as I know, no Scala's standard library APIs return **null**, but `Option`, and it is discouraged to use **null** at all in your Scala code. You can even configure your project that it will fail to compile if **null** is [used](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html).

`Option` is also `Serializable` and its normal practice to use is as class fields for values that can be empty.

If you want to use a similar approach in your Java code please check [Option](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_option) from **Vavr**. It's serializable, so it can be safely used as fields and it also has two subclasses `None` and `Some` (similarly as Scala's `Option`), so it can be used in Vavr's pattern matching:

```
Match(option).of(
    Case($Some($()), "defined"),
    Case($None(), "empty")
);
```

Answer (score 6):

In Scala, [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html) is tightly integrated into the language's API.

> Represents optional values. Instances of Option are either an instance of scala.Some or the object None.
> The most idiomatic way to use an scala.Option instance is to treat it as a collection or monad and use map,flatMap, filter, or foreach.

As you can see from the quote above, there is no `null` explanation there, because it should be used as a monad or as a collection.

In Java, [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is used to save us from NullPointerException cases, by using it as:

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

A programming language that shows the user very clearly if the variable can be null or not is [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), by using [? safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), and shows you compilation errors:

```
var a: String = "abc"
a = null // compilation error

var b: String? = "abc"
b = null // ok
print(b)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is the position, that Optional, like Stream, is an iterating «event» class, not deserving to be used as field in a "real" object.

Then there is the short-coming of not being Serializable (which one may work around).

However my opinion is that some variables may be *optional*, of cardinality 0 and 1.
Just as a *list* is valid too. With `List` fields the trend is (IMHO) that it is not let to be null initially, but to always have an (empty) list.

In the same coding style, an `Optional` ensures that only safe access is used, and especially one may map in a chaining style:

```
Optional<TextField> t = ...

String s = t.map(t::getText).orElse("N/A");
Optional<String> u = t.map(t::getText);
t.ifPresent(s -> { ... });
```

Especially the `ifPresent` ensures not working with null unintendedly.

Optional is a valuable specification.

Answer (score -1):

One reason not to use `Optional` for instance variables is that it's too easy for the `Optional` reference itself to be `null`. This violates an implied contract around `Optional`, namely that you should never create or encounter a `null` reference to an `Optional`.

```java
class Foo {
    Optional<Bar> bar;
}

Foo f = new Foo();
if (f.bar.isPresent()) { // NullPointerException
    ...
}
```

This is the simplest way to create a class with an `Optional` field in Java. In a sense the language encourages you to write code like this.

On the other hand, in Scala, the simplest way to define `Foo` is

```scala
case class Foo(bar: Option[Bar])
```

and it's so easy to do

```scala
case class Foo(bar: Option[Bar] = None)
```

both of which avoid the NPE.

Comment: if you're writing java, you've already bitten the verbosity bullet, and if you read what the authors themselves have written, this is not what they intended with that rule of thumb.

Comment: well there's this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/870178, but this dude actually does a pretty good job of representing my point of view: https://blog.codefx.org/java/stephen-colebourne-optional-a-strict-approach/