# How is javax.ws.rs.client.Entity serializing objects to json?

Tags: java, json, serialization, option-type

What serializer is [`Entity.json(T entity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#json-T-) using to serialize/deserialize objects? Is it somehow possible to use a custom serializer?

In my case the serialization is wrong because my object contains fields with the [Guava Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) data type and absent values are returned as `{"present":false}` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON serializer isn't specified by JAX-RS, it depends on your configuration. For example, Jersey JAX-RS allows several (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html), including

- MOXy
- Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)
- Jackson
- Jettison

But a better solution is not to use `Optional` (either Guava or Java 8) for fields. See http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/optional-in-java-se-8.html

> My only fear is that Optional will be overused. Please focus on using
>   it as a return type (from methods that perform some useful piece of
>   functionality) Please don't use it as the field of a Java-Bean.

Comment: Thank you, I configured the Jackson Guava module and it is working fine now. I've read the article you mentioned before but isn't `Optional` reasonable for fields in an API representation class? People that implement my client will have an explicit indication that a certain field can be null (e.g. ErrorCode) this way

Comment: Also relevant regarding use of Optional (with a response from Brian Goetz, even): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type

Answer (score 0):

Not directly solving your problem. I suggest you use **Googles Gson** as a parser. It is very flexible and configurable.

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

It also skips blank fields so the json size is not too large.

Comment: thanks, but I am using Dropwizard which already comes with Jackson