# Optional in Java Entity to replace nullable columns

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, null, option-type

I am wondering if I can get some advice regarding the use of Java 8's Optional class to wrap nullable columns in entities. What I mean is expressed in the following code example:

```
@Entity
public class Data {

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String value;

    public Optional<String> getValue() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value);
    }

    public void setValue(Optional<String> value) {
        this.value = value.orElse(null);
    }
```

The column in the database can still be made null, however, in order to check for null, one must call the getter with the isPresent() method. I like the explicitness, opposed to having to check or remember if a column is nullable. Is such a pattern common and/or recommended? If not, can you provide a good reason why I *shouldn't* do this?

Comment: Another good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-java8-optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian Goetz himself [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/5372160) this question. His verdict:

> I think routinely using it as a return value for getters would definitely be over-use.

Basically, `Optional` wasn't designed to be a general purpose `Maybe` or `Some` type. There are some things it should definitely not be used for, getters are okay but don't go nuts.

Comment: Great link, thank you. I think my example qualifies as over-use by his definition.