# Why list.sort does not use the Optional API

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 introduces a new default method on the `List` interface to sort it. It's signature is :

```
void sort(Comparator<? super E> c)
```

The documentation says:

> If the specified comparator is null then all elements in this list
>   must implement the Comparable interface and the elements' natural
>   ordering should be used.

So if you want to sort the list by it's natural order (and that your elements are comparable) you have to do `list.sort(null);` which is kind of weird of my opinion.

If they used an `Optional` the doc would stated that you can optionally provide a comparator, and that if it's not provided it will assume the elements are already comparable.

A `list.sort(null);` call would be transformed into `list.sort(Optional.empty());`.

As it's a method that it exposed to the outside world, I would find it more accurate.

Why didn't they used the new Optional API instead?

Comment: ...or just force you to pass in a non-null comparator. I'd think that would be much easier all round.

Comment: ... or match `Collections`, which provides an overload `sort()` that doesn't take any `Comparator` arguments to sort by the natural order?

Comment: Or just pass `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, it's not that hard, and also much clearer than `null`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Optional is intended to be used as a return type. That has always been the mantra of the JDK-8 developers. So they won't break their own rule by using it as an argument.

That said, I would have made the argument mandatory, and thus force the developer to use

```
list.sort(Comparator.<Foo>naturalOrder());
```

Even if I can pass null, I find the above more readable, and not much more verbose. So that's what I use in my code.

Comment: I didn't know about the first paragraph, and I agree with your last point. Thanks :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type for a longer explanation on the intention, from Brian Goetz himself (the lead JDK8 developer - or whatever his actual title is)

Comment: Thanks. They could have provided also a default method with no arguments however.

Comment: @user2336315 I don't think it would have been a good idea. This would have led developers (especially newbies) to think that any list can be sorted, without needing to provide a comparator, whatever the list contains. And this is not the case: only lists of Comparable objects can be sorted. Collections.sort() doesn't have this problem, because it's only callable with a list of Comparables as arguments.

Comment: I don't like passing `null` either but, `null` is used in many places to mean the natural ordering (e.g. `SortedSet.comparator`.

Comment: I guess it was a dilemma between coherence and cleanliness. One other thing I don't like with "null means natural ordering" is that if your intention is to pass a comparator, and if the code happens to have a bug and you inadvertently pass a null reference, the list is sorted with its natural order rather than failing with a clear exception. It's probably not a common mistake, but still...

Comment: @JBNizet There's already `Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` (I guess it was introduced before generics but still it's in the API) so I don't find your argument very convincing. Also people should read the doc before blindly run their program IMO.

Comment: @user2336315 yes, but 1. Arrays.sort() is lower level (just because arrays are lower-level: regular code shouldn't use arrays much. collections should be preferred), 2. This methods dates back to Java 1.2, when generics didn't exist yet. They could have taken a Comparable[] as argument, but this wouldn't have guaranteed that the elements were mutually comparable anyway. The more recent, generic equivalent, is Arrays.sort(T, Comparator). The old one, IMO, is there mainly for backward-compatibility reasons.

Comment: @JB Nizet: `Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)` has the property (just like its `Collections.sort` counterpart) of accepting a `null` comparator and treating it as *natural order*. So `List.sort` follows this pattern, but I agree with you that a mandatory argument was the better choice, because now the *implementor* of `List.sort` is forced to perform unchecked operations to fulfill the contract. Further, this pattern encouraged the `Stream` implementors to optimize for the `null` comparator case and treating `Comparator.naturalOrder()` as second class comparator…

Comment: For natural order I use good old `Collections.sort(list)` which is type safe and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The default method is delegating to `Arrays#sort`, which [has existed since *at least* Java 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Here's the relevant snippet for the default method:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

Observe that it's converting the list into an array and letting `Arrays#sort` handle it from there.  The default behavior for this then would fall back to what is supported for that method.

There are two reasons why I see this being preferable to adding an `Optional`:

- If you don't *have* a `Comparator` to use, or just want the "default" behavior, you can provide a `null` to it.  In this context, `null` and `Optional.isPresent()` serve the same purpose and would not earn any usability points.

  It is an annoyance to have to *provide* `null` to a function for its default behavior; better design might have been to either overload the method or allow a default `naturalOrder` instance to be passed in instead.
- The `Optional` pattern is more meant to guard against inadvertently handling a `null` reference, as opposed to being used for a `null` check.  The overhead in adding `Optional` where a simple `null` check would suffice would far outweigh its benefits, especially considering that there is no semantic difference.

Comment: There's also `Arrays.sort(Object[] o)` so they could take it from there to depending if the value is present or not. You convinced me on your last point though, so +1.

Comment: If they did that, they'd be ignoring the parameter passed which is *terrible* design.  At the bare minimum, the user as the *chance* to provide their own `Comparator`, but if they elect to pass `null`, then the natural order wins.

Comment: That’s not convincing. If the parameter was `Optional`, delegating to `Arrays.sort` just required a simple call to `orElse(null)` to convert an `Optional<Comparator>` to a nullable `Comparator`. But a single particular implementation shouldn’t be the driving force behind an API design anyway (and it isn’t). By the way, if a method has no “Since” marker, it’s usually as old as the class itself, which is in the case of `java.util.Arrays` “*Since: 1.2*”