# How to reference an empty variable of any type in java

Tags: java, variables

Let's suppose that we have these variables:

```
Integer nbr;
String str;
ApiClass someInstance;
Date date;
```

I want to state that nbr is empty, str is empty, someInstance is empty, date is empty(not assigned to any value), without using `myVar = null;` because oviously this is a bad habit.

is there any way to test if a java variable is not assigned to anything without assigning to each one `null`value.

Comment: An `int` in Java cannot be *empty*.  It can have a 0 value, but it will never have a `null` or *empty* value.  For this you should use it's boxed class `Integer`

Comment: Have a look at [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: @CraigR8806 I know that, I also know what is the default value of String & Date & Integer class, I don't want to test for each variable if it has its default value => empty... I want something more advanced and more type independent.I hope that I didn't get downvoted for this

Comment: In that case: No. There is no such thing. You can use Optional or your own implementation of the Null-Object pattern but variables do not have an implicit "hasBeenSet"-Flag. You could emulate those by adding the according bools to your class and use getters/setters to access them (and set/read the flags accordingly in those).

Comment: @Fildor Optional is exactly what I'm looking for, write it as an answer so I can accept it. thanks

Comment: a field String[] a; is null before assignment. When you assign new String[0];, the field is not null anymore. It now references an array, which is empty. If you assign new String[1];, the field is also non-null and now references a non-empty array with one element, which is a null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

**EDIT**: Please consider reading the references in the comments. You should not just replace all the null-checks with "isPresent"-checks!

Especially [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) (thanks, @ModusTollens)

---

Another way around null-Checks is the [Null-Object-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Java). But I feel Optional better suits your requirement.

To make sure all fields have been set before the object is "allowed to be used", you could also go with the builder pattern or a little simpler with an immutable object.

---

Note: I am deliberately *not* going into if using `null`s is an anti-pattern or not. I am just answering the question.

Comment: Whether null is an antipattern truly depends on a project's culture - made explicit with annotations it can be ok-ish imo, even though I prefer an explicit optional type over just annotations. At least, the annotations allow tools to check and instrument the correct use.

Comment: @yeoman I stated it explicitly because I just wanted to not start a discussion on that. But I agree with you.

Comment: @cimecut Be careful using Optional; calling the get() method when a value is not present will still return null. So you should make sure to always use "ifPresent" or "orElse". For the primitive value use OptionalInt. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/1288408), [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26328314/1288408) and [this post](https://medium.com/@bgourlie/java-s-optional-the-do-s-and-don-ts-4323151bc073#.aymzkt9d9). I'd recommend the Null-Object-Pattern.

Comment: @ModusTollens The [documentation for Optional.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) states it can never return null.  To get a null, you would need something like `orElse(null)`.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain? I always am ready to improve an answer.

Comment: @VGR You are right, I misread. But you would want to make sure to not constantly check for NoSuchElementException either.

Comment: @ModusTollens You can also use the "isPresent" method instead of risking the exception. But the point is after all, that the OP does not want to rely on a semantical meaning of a field's value. I.e. "null == not set" or "0 == not set" or "1900-01-01 == not set" and that's exactly what Optional is giving him.

Comment: @Fildor You *can* also use "isPresent", but Oracle itself does not recommend it (quoted from [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html): "However, this is not the recommended use of Optional (it's not much of an improvement over nested null checks), and there are more idiomatic alternatives, which we explore below."). That's why I mentioned "ifPresent" and "orElse".

Comment: @Fildor There is a fair amount of documentation, including the explanations in Modus’ links, explaining why Optional is intended for method return types, and should never be used for general “nullable variables.”

Comment: @ModusTollens Again, I agree with you on that. But if your goal is simply to take away the semantic meaning of `null`, then Optional gives you that.

Comment: @VGR I agree with that, too.

Comment: @ModusTollens Ah, wait ... Now I get what you are thinking ... I am *not* advocating just replacing `if( x!=null )` with `if( x.isPresent() )`. *Of course* he should make use of `ifPresent`, `orElse` ...

Comment: @Fildor sorry, but I couldn't resist throwing this pebble into the calm water :D Btw. it's such a shame that Java's built-in Optional is not a Collection. In fact, I would prefer it even being a List, albeit a rather simple one. Plus, directly itself a Monad. Nothing calls for monadic binding like an Optional...

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about local variables, this is not possible and a compile error. You cannot access a local variable before it has been assigned a value.

For static or instance fields of a reference type there is no difference between not initializing them and initializing them with null. The initial value is always null, not some distinct "not set" value. Similar for primitive fields, they will be initialized to 0 resp. false, if you don't do it yourself.