# How to do Java Optional if present do something or else throw?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, option-type

What I want to do is, updating a customer if it is present but if there is no customer then throw an exception. But I could not find the correct stream function to do that. How can I achieve this ?

```
public Customer update(Customer customer) throws Exception {
        Optional<Customer> customerToUpdate = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId());
        customerToUpdate.ifPresentOrElse(value -> return customerRepository.save(customer),
        throw new Exception("customer not found"));
    }
```

I could not return the value coming from save function because it is saying that it is void method and not expecting return value.

Comment: Don't store the optional, immediately use `orElseThrow();` after findById and store the nonnull result.

Comment: You can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485751/java-8-optional-ifpresent-return-object-orelsethrow-exception

Comment: I would put exceptions first, then the "actual code". So, probably `customer = customerRepository.findById(...).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(...))` and then `/* some more code */; return customerRepository.save(customer);` would be more readable and maintainable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993428/throw-exception-in-optional-in-java8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Guillaume F. already said in the comments, you could just use `orElseThrow` here:

```java
Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("customer not found"));
return customerRepository.save(customer);
```

By the way, avoid throwing `Exception`, as that exception is too broad. Use a more specific type, like `NotFoundException`.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Yes as you said, I will not throw exception just wrote it for the question, I am defining custom exceptions with controller advice and global exception handlers etc.

Comment: But this code snippet is also giving error and maybe not correct as syntax

Comment: Well, you need to remove the `throw` keyword. `orElseThrow` requires one to *supply* the exception, and not *throw* it. (Of course, the exception is eventually thrown by the `orElseThrow` method.)