# How can i put a null check in a parameter of a method?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

like

```
x = setDetailsFromSegment(getDetails.getProductList().getProductDetails().get(0).getItinerary().getOriginDestinationList(),
                          getDetailsResponse.getProductDetailsList().getProductDetails().get(0).getFareList());
```

Here `setDetailsFromSegment()` is my method and I want to check whether the parameters are null or not before invoking the method using java 8.

Comment: has a null check been changed in java-8?

Comment: So, do it. What's the problem? But you really shouldn't have to do that. A method that (at least seems to) return a List shoud never, ever return null. Make them return an empty list.

Comment: as JB Nizet mentioned - you can very well check Null before calling this method. And about the list, you need to check for list size as well, else you may encounter ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Also you might want to read about method chaining in regards of the Law of Demeter.

Comment: @JBNizet ya ,but the getDetails may not always give productList,so i have to verify whether it is empty or not.They wont return null,but when i use get(0) they will encounter ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Comment: @Abie yep..you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the necessarity of null-checks if possible.

If you can change `getOriginDestinationList()` and `getFareList()` you should make them return [Collections.emptyList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--). If you are not returning lists, you might consider to use an [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). But be careful where to use and Optional and where not. See for example [Should Java 8 getters return optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555)

If you cannot change the return value of the methods, you have to execute the checks before you are calling the methods. [Objects.requireNotNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) could be helpful here.

Beside this your code has a problem because of excessive method chaining. You might need to check the return values for every method. And it is hard to read. And I would not use "x" as a variable name ;-).

Comment: I am not returning the lists nor i can change the implementation of the lists(ie make them Optional).These lists are got from the object -->'getDetails'.This is a response after I sent the request.So lists in that objects may or may not be null!   So while passing as arguments I need to check Null pointer and ArrayIndexOutOfBound. Also the variable name 'x' is just a dummy one.I too won't use the same;)

Comment: Then you have to execute your checks before you call the setDetailsFromSegment. I would move the two calls into a seperate method where you can apply all necessary checks. Your call could look like '... = setDetailsFromSegment(getOriginDestinationList(), getFareList());'. The methods 'getOriginDestinationList()' and  'getFareList()' could do all necessary checks (if-statements) and they should return an empty list if no result is present.