# I need an advice on null safety in Java

Tags: java, null, kotlin-null-safety

I've been reading articles on beeing null safe in java, and how it's bad to `return null`, or of that sin, that is passing `null` as an argument. I get that it simplifies life, and people don't always read documentation, so they don't know wheather a method can `return null`, or if `null` can be passed to it. Annotations seem to just pollute the code, and there is no Kotlin-like [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) mechanism. In my current project I try to design everything in such a manner, that null is almost unnecessary, at least for the end-user.

I want to create a change listener (something like [`javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html)), such that i can pass a previous and a current value to the `changed()` method. The thing is, I want it to be null safe, so I don't want to ever pass a `null` as an argument, even though it can change from no value to some value, or from some value to no value. I could add two additional methods for that situation and have something like:

```
public inteface ChangeListener<T> {
    void valueSet(T current);
    void valueChanged(T previous, T current);
    void valueCleared(T previous);
}
```

This approach seems excessive though. I could also use 
[`java.util.Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as arguments, but that adds additional boxing:

```
public inteface ChangeListener<T> {
    void changed(Optional<T> previous, Optional<T> current);
}
```

Is there a more elegant option? Or should I force user to use some sort of a [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)? Although that will create problems with the need to extend some classes. I could also stop caring, specify in the documentation what will happen if `null` is used, and let the user find the source of all the NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: It seems that you have covered pretty much all the usual options.

Comment: `void changed(Optional<T> previous, Optional<T> current);` - this does not really give you any benefit. To be really `null`-safe, you would have to check whether the parameters themself were `null`.

Comment: You can put the `@Nullable` annotation on `previous` parameter to show that it can be `null`.

Comment: @Turing85 Not sure why you insist on checking Optional for null - a null Optional is a design error (i.e. a bug).

Comment: @assylias well you either want to be `null`-safe or not. If OP checks for a documented not-`null`, it would only be consistent to check whether the passed `Optional` is not-`null` as well.

Comment: @Turing85 One could pass `null` instead of an `Optional`, but that would be caused by user's design (if one decided to use my interface). On my side I could assure, that it will always, empty or not, be an `Optional` object.

Comment: @assylias just to make my point clear, here is a cite from Brian Goetz on the topic: ["*You should almost never use it as a field of something or a method parameter.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/4216641)

Comment: What's the problem with passing nulls? If the previous/new value is a null, then you should pass a null because that is the actual value. Passing anything else would not accurately represent the transition.

Comment: @Turing85 Agreed, in this case `Optional` usage is like burning a house just to get rid of a mouse - an overkill. Additional methods introduce unnecessary complexity. I think, I'll just, as [SeverityOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228808/i-need-an-advice-on-null-safety-in-java/48229102#48229102) said, document the behaviour. Maybe I will get more comfortable with `@Nullable` and `@Nonnull`

Comment: @Maniek there is still the option of [`Objects.requireNonNull(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-)...

Comment: @Turing85 I'm using [Guava's Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) for null and argument checking, but it's not that I wanted to check that. I wanted to make sure, that the user won't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be a bit careful when people tell you "XYZ considered harmful". I've seen people do away with constructors altogether in favour of factory methods (such as `Optional.of(...)`), but as with everything, there's no single correct answer.

You seem to be struggling with trying to achieve several things (using simple code, having only one method in the listener, not using null values) that are mutually exclusive. So stop worrying and focus on what's important.

If your API users are idiots, and they don't read documentation, that's not really your problem. Null is not something dirty; it means "undefined". What is dubious is to use null if something unexpected happened, like "file not found", which should ideally be dealt with via an exception.

If "undefined" is a correct representation of an unset value in your API, then there's nothing wrong with using null.

Comment: I completely agree. `null` is a very good representation for an unset value, as it will immediately throw an exception whenever someone tries to call any method on it, making sure it can't be confused for some valid value.