# Java 8 "Optional" bad practice?

Tags: android, kotlin, option-type, rx-java2

I've a code:

```
val d = Single
            .zip<List<X>, Optional<Y>, DataContent>(
                    xSingle,
                    YSingle,
                    BiFunction { x, y ->
                        val b = if (y.isPresent()) {
                            y.get()
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                        return@BiFunction DataContent(x, b)
                    })
            .subscribe({ data ->
                ...
            }, { t ->
                ...
            })
```

I've heard, that using `Optional` to check null value as shown in an example, is bad practice. Is that true? Why? Can someone show an alternative using `RxJava2`?

Comment: RxJava2 will not allow publishing "null" values, I think that you should use Maybe and just don't publish "null".

Comment: `if (y.isPresent()) {
                            y.get()
                        } else {
                            null
                        }` is the same as just `y.orElse(null)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, `Optional` has a restricted set of use cases and is in danger of being overrused. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/5241933) by Java author Brian Goetz to understand these (emphasis added):

> But we did have a clear intention when adding this [java.util.Optional] feature, and it was not to be a general purpose Maybe or Some type, as much as many people would have liked us to do so. Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result", and using null for such was overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.
>
> For example, you probably should never use it for something that returns an array of results, or a list of results; instead return an empty array or list. **You should almost never use it as a field of something or a method parameter.**

In the original example posted, `Optional<Y>` is used as a method parameter so this is against Java best practices. Besides, `Maybe` is idiomatic in RxJava.

Assuming you have something like the following:

```
class X
class Y
data class DataContent constructor(val listOfX: List<X>, val y: Y)
```

You could write a function like this that would seem to fit your use case:

```
fun zipToDataContent(maybeListOfX: Maybe<List<X>>, maybeY: Maybe<Y>): Maybe<DataContent> =
        Maybe.zip<List<X>, Y, DataContent>(
                maybeListOfX,
                maybeY,
                BiFunction { listOfX, y -> DataContent(listOfX, y) })
```

Tests:

```
@Test
fun testZipToDataContentWithRealY() {
    val x = X()
    val y = Y()

    val maybeListOfX = Maybe.just(listOf(x))
    val maybeY = Maybe.just(y)

    zipToDataContent(maybeListOfX, maybeY).test()
            .assertOf {
                Maybe.just(DataContent(listOf(x), y))
            }
}

@Test
fun testZipToDataContentWithEmptyY() {
    val x = X()

    val maybeListOfX = Maybe.just(listOf(x))
    val maybeY = Maybe.empty<Y>()

    zipToDataContent(maybeListOfX, maybeY).test()
            .assertOf {
                Maybe.empty<DataContent>()
            }
}
```