# Rewrite if-statement using Optional map and filter

Tags: java, validation, lambda, option-type, predicate

I have a predicate which accepts `Optional<LocalDateTime>` and I want to check if it is present and the `LocalDateTime` is before current date.

I can write it with if statements which would look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean test(Optional<ResetPassword> resetPassword) {
    if (resetPassword.isPresent()) {
        if (!resetPassword.get().getValidUntil().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new CustomException("Incorrect date");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How could I rewrite this using the `Optional.map` and  `Optional.filter` functions?

Comment: `.map` and `.filter` are for streams, which usually comes from a collection. There is no point in using these in a non-collection object.

Comment: @KarelG `Optional` has `map` and `filter` methods, too.

Comment: true but I kinda find it obsolete. Worthless.

Comment: That's an interesting opinion.

Comment: You should not use `Optional` as a parameter to anything. It's meant to be used only as a return type.

Comment: Well, you can do that after a collection stream to have the same semantics at the end of the chain (eg after `.findAny()`) to convert the object into another type if desired. But outside that? It is also strange that OP is passing an `Optional` as a parameter. I only use it as return.

Comment: @marstran *"You should never use an Optional as a parameter to anything."* As an unqualified assertive statement this is just plain wrong. It's a matter of style. Having an optional as a parameter type makes it clear to readers that the parameter might be null, which makes the code easier to work with.

Comment: @LiolikasBolikas: There doesn't seem to be a good way to solve your problem with `map` and `filter`. I think your solution is about as good as it's possible to make it. The reason why it is hard is, I think, it that the combination of results that you want doesn't translate well to the logic of `Optional`. In your case you want to work with `boolean`, `ResetPassword` and exception, and that doesn't really fit the model. I think...

Comment: @Lii It's certainly not an unqualified statement. It is a statement that originates with Brian Goetz himself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/4137489.

Comment: I've also argued against the use of `Optional` as a method parameter. If this is intended to be used as a `Predicate`, though, then its usage in this case might be warranted. This would let you take a stream of `Optional<ResetPassword>` and filter them using this predicate. While semantically this particular case seems a bit odd, there might be other cases where it's useful. More concerning is the fact that this method throws an exception in some cases, which makes it entirely unsuitable for most uses as a `Predicate`.

Comment: The purpose of this predicate was to validate ResetPassword object if it's present and if its date time is before current date time, and if not i just throw exception which is handled by Global exception handler, the reason i added it to Predicate is to just bundle few predicates, iterate over them and check rules so there would be no multiple if statements. What you would suggest for me to change in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use an `Optional` as a parameter to anything. Instead, you should let your function take a `ResetPassword`, and only call it if the value of the `Optional` is present.
Like this:

```
public void test(ResetPassword resetPassword) {
    if (!resetPassword.getValidUntil().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
        throw new CustomException("Incorrect date");
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
resetPasswordOptional
    .ifPresent(rp -> test(rp));
```

Comment: *"You should never use an Optional as a parameter to anything."* As an unqualified assertive statement this is just plain wrong. It's a matter of style. Having an optional as a parameter type makes it clear to readers that it might be null.

Comment: @Lii It's certainly not an unqualified statement. It is a statement that originates with Brian Goetz himself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/4137489.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one will help you, in addition, pay attention to the exception which one you throw if it is `RuntimeException` your app will crash in case of a false condition.

```
 public boolean test(Optional<ResetPassword> resetPassword) {
        return resetPassword.isPresent() && resetPassword
                .map(ResetPassword::getValidUntil)
                .filter(localDateTime -> localDateTime.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException("Incorrect date")) != null;
    }
```

Comment: That should work! I think what the poster already has is clearer, but this is shorter and at least it uses `map` and `filter`! (If that's your goal...)