# Optional flatmap in Java has NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

Optional is used to avoid NullPointerException in Java 8.

But code has NullPointerException when I use Optional flatmap.

Code as below:

```
import java.util.Optional;
public class test2 {
  public static class Car {
    public Optional<Insurance> insurance;

    public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
      return insurance;
    }
  }

  public static class Insurance {
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
  }

  public static class Person {
    public Optional<Car> car;

    public Optional<Car> getCar() {
      return car;
    }
  }
  public static String getCarInsuranceName(Optional<Person> person) {
    return person.flatMap(Person::getCar)
            .flatMap(Car::getInsurance)
            .map(Insurance::getName)
            .orElse("Unknown");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person();
    Car car = new Car();
    Insurance insurance = new Insurance();
//    insurance.name = "test";
//    car.insurance = Optional.of(insurance);
    person.car = Optional.of(new Car());
    String result= getCarInsuranceName(Optional.of(person));
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Console information：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:241)
    at test2.getCarInsuranceName(test2.java:29)
    at test2.main(test2.java:41)
```

`person` variable indeed has no insurance. But the result I want to get is `Unknown`, not NullPointerException.

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_192-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

When `person` has `insurance` and `insurance` hasn't `name`, I got `Unknown`.

I want to know Why?

Comment: I suspect he just simply needed something like .findAny().orElse("Unknown")?   I don't think .orElse on its own would finalize the stream the way he intended?

Comment: Reopened because this question is more about the intricacies of using an `Optional` chain, and the most correct answer (use the chain in a different manner) differs substantially from the canonical NPE question.

Comment: This is from `Modern Java in Action` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `insurance` field of `Car` is always `null`. Never ever allow an `Optional` to be `null`, this defeats the whole idea of having an `Optional`. And will very often cause a surprising `NullPointerException`. This is what happens in your code too.

I suggest the following version of the `Car` class:

```
    public static class Car {
        private Insurance insurance = null;

        public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(insurance);
        }
    }
```

It fixes the problem so the output now is:

> Unknown

There’s no point (that I can see) in declaring `insurance` an `Optional`. It’s enough that your getter returns one. `Optional` is primarily for return values. It has few other good uses.

**EDIT:** @chrylis commented and doesn’t seem to like the combination of a plain reference field and a getter returning an `Optional`. I see nothing wrong with it, but if you prefer to keep your field an `Optional` as in the question, that’s certainly possible too. Then you just need to make sure that it isn’t `null`:

```
public static class Car {
    private Optional<Insurance> insurance = Optional.empty();

    public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }
}
```

This too fixes the program so we get the output above.

Whether a getter should be returning an `Optional` is discussed [in this question: Should Java 8 getters return optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type) My first snippet above seems more to follow the recommendations in [the least upvoted answer by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403766/5772882).

Comment: Instead, use the standard JavaBean idiom and return `null` from `Insurance getInsurance()`. Using `map` instead of `flatMap` Does The Right Thing.

Comment: So you’re objecting to using `Optional` at all in the first place? That’s a valid opinion too. More discussion here: [Should Java 8 getters return optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type)

Comment: Not objecting to using `Optional` *entirely*, but it's not idiomatic to use it here, especially when the backing field for the property is a plain reference.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, @chrylis. I have edited (still with respect for the asker’s way of doing things).