# Compare String in ENUM

Tags: java, enums

I want to implement storing of enabled or disabled features into database row. When some String value is received from them the network I would like to compare it into ENUM.

ENUM:

```
public enum TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString {
    Authorize("authorize", 0), // index 0 in bit string
    Authorize3d("authorize3d", 1), // index 1 in bit String
    Sale("sale", 2), // index 2 in bit String
    Sale3d("sale3d", 3), // index 3 in bit String
}

Map<TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString, Boolean> featureMaps =
    config.initFromDatabaseValue(optsFromDatabase);

featureMaps.get(transaction.transactionType);
```

The best way is to use `featureMaps.get(TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString.Sale);`

But I don't know the incoming string what would be.

Now I get warning `Unlikely argument type String for get(Object) on a Map<TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString,Boolean>`

Is there any other way to make a query into the ENUM without knowing the key?

Comment: Enum constants are just that: constants. They should be uppercase.

Comment: use `TerminalConfigurationnFeatureBitString.valueOf(transaction.transactionType)` and then call `featureMaps.get()` with the returned, resolved enum

Comment: he doesn't need the map in this case

Comment: @Lino It's bad practice to rely on the name of an enum, just as it is to rely on the ordinal. It leads to brittle code. You should be able to refactor variable names without fear of changing runtime behaviour. If you rely on methods like that, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like these, I often find myself adding a static method `getByX` which does a lookup based upon a property of the enum:

```
public enum BitString {
    //...

    public static Optional<BitString> getByTransactionType(String transactionType)
    {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(x -> x.transactionType.equals(transactionType))
            .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum TransactionStatus
{
    ENABLED, NOT_ENABLED, NOT_SUPPORTED
}

TransactionStatus status = BitString.getBygetByTransactionType(transaction.transactionType)
    .map(bitString -> featureMaps.get(bitString))
    .map(enabled -> enabled ? TransactionStatus.ENABLED : TransactionStatus.NOT_ENABLED)
    .orElse(TransactionStatus.NOT_SUPPORTED);
```

Comment: One additional question: How I can return false? Not RuntimeException?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't (or rather shouldn't) sometimes return a boolean and sometimes an enum. You could return null (`orElse(null)`), or an `Optional<BitString>` (remove `orElseThrow` entirely).

Comment: Can you show me how should I compare the String if I have return Optional<BitString>?

Comment: Is there a way to print a message if it's not found "Transaction is not supported" and if it's false to get "Transaction is not enabled"?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You have 3 potential states, so I would define an enum. See updated answer. The rest is up to you ;)

Comment: just to know. Is there a solution without second ENUM?

Comment: Yes, you could return a boxed Boolean: TRUE, FALSE and null. But I wouldn't.

Comment: Ok, when the status is set in ENUM how I can check it for example with `if(...)` case? How to get the status from the ENUM?

Comment: "The rest is up to you ;)"

Comment: Help please. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825648/5515060), you can just generate a `static` lookup map inside your `enum` which maps an enums transaction type to the actual enum:

```
private static final Map<String, TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString> TRANSACTION_TYPE_TO_ENUM = 
   Arrays.stream(values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
       TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString::getTransactionType, 
       Function.identity()
   );
```

And then have a lookup method, also inside the enum:

```
public static TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString getByTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString bitString = TRANSACTION_TYPE_TO_ENUM.get(transactionType);
    if(bitString == null) throw new NoSuchElementException(transactionType);
    return bitString;
}
```

This in a way more performant than the mentioned answer, because the `Map` is created the first time the `enum` is loaded (So when it is the first time referenced). And thus the iteration happens only once. Also `Map`s have a rather fast lookup time so you could say that getting an enum this way works O(1) (when ignoring the initial computation time of O(n))

Comment: I thought it might be nice if Lombok could generate stuff like this automatically. Maybe I'll fork it one day.

Comment: @Michael I know at least that Swagger does it, and I use a lot of swagger to generate my models

Comment: if already using java 8 stream so smartly, why not use `Optional` to avoid the null check in the static method?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher this is very opiniated, but I just don't like to use `Optional` for simple conditional logic, of course returning an `Optional` would have the same effect as returning `null` I would just give the caller the responsibilty to do an exceptional action if nothing is found

Comment: it is my opinion that Optional is a good fit here. there is no "too simple" condition that is below the need for Optional. it was designed to replace null checks with fluent api

Comment: i dont mean return an Optional. I meant replace the if statement with Optional

Comment: @SharonBenAsher It was **not** designed to replace null checks with a fluent API. It was designed ["to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result", and using null for such was overwhelmingly likely to cause errors"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/1898563).

Comment: something like  `return Optional.ofNullabe(TRANSACTION_TYPE_TO_ENUM.get(transactionType)).orElseThorw(() -> new NoSuchElementException(transactionType);`

Comment: @Michael,  well, [Oracle seems to think differently](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'm literally quoting Brian Goetz, Java's lead language architect. And **your own link disagrees with you** "The purpose of Optional is not to replace every single null reference in your codebase but rather to help design better APIs in which—just by reading the signature of a method—users can tell whether to expect an optional value"

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your `enum` with extra static method which will try to convert given `String` on `enum` item:

```
enum TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString {
    Authorize("authorize", 0), // index 0 in bit string
    Authorize3d("authorize3d", 1), // index 1 in bit String
    Sale("sale", 2), // index 2 in bit String
    Sale3d("sale3d", 3); // index 3 in bit String

    private final String value;
    private final int index;

    TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString(String value, int index) {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public static Optional<TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString> fromValue(String value) {
        for (TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString item : values()) {
            if (item.value.equals(value)) {
                return Optional.of(item);
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

In case option is not found, return `Optional.empty()`. If feature is not present it means `String` representation does not represent any feature. Usage:

```
public void test() {
    EnumMap<TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString, Boolean> featureMaps = new EnumMap<>(
        TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString.class);

    Optional<TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString> feature = TerminalConfigurationFeatureBitString.fromValue("authorize");
    if (!feature.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Feature is not foudn!");
    } else {
        Boolean authorize = featureMaps.get(feature.get());
        if (authorize != null && authorize) {
            System.out.println("Feature is enabled!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Feature is disabled!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but when key is not found how I can resume the code? I don't need IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, In this case just `return null;` instead of throwing exception. Or choose default value which will be returned in that case. There is many option which depends from scenario you have.

Comment: It turns out that I need to add one more case: If the transaction is not found I want to return null and print not found message. If the transaction is not enabled I would like to return message: Not enabled. Any idea how this can be implemented?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, Use `Optional` class. In case it returns empty `Optional` it means given `String` is not valid feature. After that check feature in `Map`. If `map.get(...)` returns `null` or `false` it means feature is disabled; otherwise - `enabled`.