# How can I return boolean value using Optional.ifPresent

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I have some problems with using `Optional.ifPresent` statement. I would like to reduce number of `NullPointerExceptions`, so I decided to use `Optional` values.

Also I am trying to avoid a ladder of `if` statements anti-pattern.

So I implemented `Optional.isPresent` statement. But it's not really that what I expected.

Please look at these listings:

This is a part of my service:

```
    if (getAllComputerProducers().isPresent()) {
        if (isComputerProducerAlreadyExist(computerProducer))
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    computerProducerRepository.save(computerProducer);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

`getAllComputerProducers` function looks like that:

```
private Optional<List<ComputerProducer>> getAllComputerProducers() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(computerProducerRepository.findAll());
}
```

As you can see, this function returns `Optional` of `List`.

The `isComputerProducerAlreadyExist` function is implemented like that:

```
private boolean isComputerProducerAlreadyExist(ComputerProducer computerProducer) {
    return getAllComputerProducers()
            .get()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(producer -> producer.getProducerName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(computerProducer.getProducerName()));
}
```

It's so much code and I believe that it could be made simpler.
My target is to reduce code to one line command like:

```
getAllCimputerProducers().ifPresent(***and-here-some-anyMatch-boolean-function***)
```

but I can't insert there a function which returns something. How can I do it?

Regards to everyone :)

Comment: You can't return from the method in which you invoke `ifPresent`, from inside `ifPresent`: it's a fundamental limitation of lambdas. You just have to use an `if` checking `isPresent()`, and return in the block.

Comment: The [ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) has no return value.

Comment: [From a Java Language Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555): "_For example, you probably should never use it for something that returns an array of results, or a list of results; instead return an empty array or list._"

Comment: But I also can't do something like that: getAllSomething().ifPresent().stream().anyMatch(something-here)

I want to check if something in list match to argument given to the function, but only if list exists.

Comment: One of the clean code rules : never return NULL by a function. Instead throw an exception. If you use this rule, you will no need to use Optional at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
private boolean isComputerProducerAlreadyExist(ComputerProducer computerProducer){
    return this.getAllComputerProducers()
            .map((List<ComputerProducer> computerProducers) -> computerProducers.stream()
                    .anyMatch(producer -> producer.getProducerName().equalsIgnoreCase(computerProducer.getProducerName())))
            .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

Or instead of loading all computer producers load only the ones using its name.

```
private boolean isComputerProducerAlreadyExist(ComputerProducer computerProducer){
    return computerProducerRepository.findByName(computerProducer.getProducerName()).isEmpty();
}
```

And as far as I know Spring supports also "exist" methods for repositories without even the need to load the Entity.

Comment: I'm not sure how I completely overlooked that last sentence. But at least I can [confirm](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-11-0) that it is supported from Spring Data JPA 1.11.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work

```
Predicate<ComputerProducer> cpPredicate = producer -> producer.getProducerName()
    .equalsIgnoreCase(computerProducer.getProducerName());

boolean compProdExists = getAllCimputerProducers()
    .map(list -> list.stream()
        .filter(cpPredicate)
        .findFirst()))
    .isPresent();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `computerProducer.getProducerName()` to repository to get the existing record. Method name will be '`findByProducerName(String producerName)`', if producerName has unique constraint, return type will be `Optional<ComputerProducer>`, else `Optional<List<ComputerProducer>>`. However, JPA returns empty list instead of null, so optional on list is not required.