# Coding efficiently using any latest library features

Tags: java, java-8

I have a specific code block and I would like to use it more efficiently, shortly using any feautures coming later than Java 8. I do not know if there exists any, so maybe I will continue doing it like before if you do not have any suggestion. This is the code block which I would like to modify:

```java
if(page != null) {
  coPage = companyService.findByCity(city, Integer.valueOf(page)-1);
}else {
  page="1";
  coPage = companyService.findByCity(city, 0);
}
```

I tried to do it using Optional but I have a problem with the variable "page" because I assign a value to local variable inside the lambda expression which compiler does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Optional is not designed to replace null checks. It's not. Stop trying to replace null checks by methods of Optional. That's not what it's for.

Comment: ok, I will keep it in my mind. Thanks..

Comment: I would rewrite that code as `companyPage = companyService.findByCity(city, page == null ? 0 : (Integer.parseInt(page) - 1));` This uses features from Java 1.0. And they still exist in Java 12.

Comment: How about `if (page == null) page = "1"; coPage = companyService.findByCity(city, Integer.valueOf(page)-1);`. Also, use `parseInt` instead of `valueOf`.

Comment: Yes, looks better. Thumbs up. :)=

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to do with Optional:

```
coPage = companyService.findByCity(city, Integer.METHOD(Optional.ofNullable(page).orElse("1"))-1);
```

where METHOD is one of [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) respectively.

However, it's generally better to use Optional in the following manner, as [specified by Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/5699679)

> [Optional is] a limited mechanism for library method return types where there [needs] to be a clear way to represent "no result", and using null for such [is] overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.