# How to format as well as compare DateTime(if one date is null) in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

How to modify following Date Comparison using Java 8 which reduce whole these methods into less lines which includes Null Safety too?

```
//Format and convert to date
private static Date handleDate(String dateInString) {
    if(dateInString == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        return formatter.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

//Checks if dates are equal
private static boolean dateEquals(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if (date1 == null && date2 != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (date2 == null && date1 != null) {
        // We already have data, don't want null there then.
        return false;
    }

    if (date1 != null && date2 != null) {
        if(date1.equals(date2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Main
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date current = handleDate("2019-09-02T00:00:00");
    Date existing = handleDate("2019-09-02T01:00:00");

    System.out.println(dateEquals(existing, current));
```

Also I do not want to have null check, so is there any utility doing so?

Comment: One of the possible simplification `private static boolean dateEquals(Date date1, Date date2) {
        return date1 == null && date2 == null || date1 != null && date1.equals(date2);
    }`

Comment: Any reason for using legacy `Date` instead of java-8 `LocalDate` or other related ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to represent an unparseable date string with `null`? I am trying, and I can’t find a situation where this makes sense. You’d rather want to discover the error and ask you user to correct it.

Comment: @Naman or [`return Objects.equals(date1, date2);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)…

Answer (score 4):

For null-tolerant comparisons: `java.util.Objects.equals(date1, date2)` (since Java 7)

For formatting I'm not aware of any such utility.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid `Date` class

You are using the wrong date-time class. `Date` was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. And that class represents a moment in UTC, but your input lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone.

## `LocalDateTime`

The `LocalDateTime` class is appropriate to represent a date and a time-of-day lacking any context of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Your input is in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
LocalDateTime x = LocalTimeDate.parse( "2019-09-02T00:00:00" ) ;
```

Compare as shown in the other Answer.

```
int result =  Objects.equals( x , y ) ;
```

## Tolerating nulls

If you want to tolerate nulls in your input string, write your own wrapper around parsing. Return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) possibly containing a `LocalDateTime`. If your are new to `Optional`, do not get all excited and go sprinkling them throughout your codebase. That class is [intended only for return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/642706).

```
public Optional < LocalDateTime > parsePossibleNull ( String input )
{
    LocalDateTime ldt = null;
    if ( Objects.isNull( input ) )
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable( ldt );
    } else
    {
        try
        {
            ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
            return Optional.of( ldt );
        } catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
        {
            return Optional.ofNullable( ldt );
        }
    }
}
```

### ⚠ Tolerating nulls is unwise

This much toleration of nulls is likely unwise. While your code should be defensive against invalid inputs, parsing/handling code should generally *not* take responsibility for such poor inputs, nor should it pass faulty inputs along the chain. Usually it is much wiser to **reject bad input as early as possible**, throwing an exception if need be.

### `Optional` types are comparable

But if you insist, you can compare the `Optional<LocalDateTime>` objects.

To quote the Javadoc:

> The other object is considered equal if:
>
> • it is also an Optional and;
>
> • both instances have no value present or;
>
> • the present values are "equal to" each other via equals().

Try it.

```
String x = "2019-09-02T00:00:00";
String y = null; // "2019-09-02T01:00:00";

Optional < LocalDateTime > xOpt = this.parsePossibleNull( x );
Optional < LocalDateTime > yOpt = this.parsePossibleNull( y );

boolean same = Objects.equals( xOpt , yOpt );

System.out.println( "xOpt = " + xOpt );
System.out.println( "yOpt = " + yOpt );
System.out.println( "same: " + same );
```

> xOpt = Optional[2019-09-02T00:00]
>
> yOpt = Optional.empty
>
> same: false

…and…

> xOpt = Optional[2019-09-02T00:00]
>
> yOpt = Optional[2019-09-02T01:00]
>
> same: false

…and…

> xOpt = Optional[2019-09-02T00:00]
>
> yOpt = Optional[2019-09-02T00:00]
>
> same: true

Comment: @fatherazrael True. You could wrap the parsing to detect the null. From there you might want to return an `Optional`. Also, your parsing should trap any `DateTimeParseException` in case of unexpected input strings.

Comment: Do we actually need to parse ISO-8601 formatted strings, when all we want to do, is comparing them?

Comment: @Holger Yes, we must parse. "2019-09-02T00:00:00" vs "2019-09-02T00:00"  and others.

Comment: @BasilBourque ok, I should not have just referred to the ISO-8601. The OP’s original code used the fixed pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`, having all fields down to seconds mandatory and no units smaller than a second. So it looks like for this particular use case, just comparing the strings would work. It would be easy to formulate a general solution which only parses if both strings are non-null and have different lengths. By the way, you have it swapped one time, `LocalTimeDate` should be `LocalDateTime`.