# Use mapped stream item downstream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to do something like this:

```java
servicesList.parallelStream()
    .map(service-> pluginService.fetchSentinelFileAsString(projectModel, branch))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .map(model -> service.fetch(model));
```

Note that the `service` parameter in the first lambda is reused in the `foreach` lambda.   This isn't legal but perhaps there's a way to do it.

Let me describe what that code is doing in case it helps:

- I have a list of references to services
- I want to use the service to get an `Optional`
- If the `Optional` is `present` I want to use the service again to process the content of the `Optional`

Put another way, I want to sorta reuse a value that was *mapped* in a previous stream item.

I really *think of* this as being one stream, but obviously each stream operation passes exactly ONE item to the next stage of the pipeline and this exceeds that limitations.

Comment: The lambda used in the first map does not use the service parameter at all. Is that intentional?

Comment: _the service parameter in the first lambda is reused in the `foreach` lambda._  there's no forEach operation in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply pass your service in a tuple (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry) to the downstream:

```
     servicesList.parallelStream()
    .map(service-> new SimpleEntry<>(service, pluginService.fetchSentinelFileAsString(projectModel, branch)))
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
    .map(e -> e.getKey().fetch(e.getValue()));
```

As you can see, the key of the entry will be the service, and the result of the fetchSentinelFileAsString call will be the value.
At least I would do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be possible based on handling non-empty `Optional` inside the first `map`:

```java
servicesList.parallelStream()
    .map(service -> pluginService
        .fetchSentinelFileAsString(projectModel, branch) // Optional
        .map(model -> service.fetch(model))
    )
    .forEach(fetchedModel -> doSomething(fetchedModel));
```

Or, taking into account that the result of `fetchSentinelFileAsString` does not depend on the services in the list which should be applied only to non-null result:

```java
pluginService.fetchSentinelFileAsString(projectModel, branch)
    .ifPresent(model -> serviceList.parallelStream()
        .forEach(service -> service.fetch(model))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `service` will only be available inside of your lambda.
You can compare this to a parameter only being available inside of the body of a method

In this case, you can leverage `Optional`'s fluent API to directly invoke the service like in the following which will output a `Stream<Optional<T>>`

```java
servicesList.parallelStream()
            .map(service-> pluginService.fetchSentinelFileAsString(projectModel, branch)
                                        .map(service::fetch)
            )
            ...
```

There is also the misusage of `get()` that should be avoided at all costs. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/5050667) from Brian Goetz