# How to convert Optional<List<Integer>> to Optional<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, option-type

I've tried to do the following, but it doesn't work

```
Optional<List<Integer>> listOne = someAPI.call()
// convert
Optional<ArrayList<Integer>> listTwo = new ArrayList<>(listOne); // doesn't work
Optional<ArrayList<Integer>> listTwo = Optional.of(new ArrayList(listOne)); // also not working
```

Note that the first API returns `Optional<List>`. And I need to send `Optional<ArrayList>` to another API.

Comment: first get the list out of the optional using on e of those method here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html not recommend to use get as there prpatily that the optional empty use one of those or method then the list the arraylist constructor as you did

Comment: Why not just use an empty list to represent “no elements” and avoid the extra complication of the `Optional`?

Comment: Agreed with you but API is written by someone else so I have no control over return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert it like this:

`Optional<ArrayList<Integer>> listTwo = listOne.map(ArrayList::new);`

Answer (score 3):

By making use of `Optional<ArrayList<Integer>>` you piggyback one contrived problem on top of the other.

## Don't wrap Collections with Optional

Any `Collection` by itself could represent the *absence of data* by being *empty*. And you can safely interact with an empty collection. Wrapping it with an `Optional` is redundant.

Here is a quote from the [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555) by *Brian Goetz*, Java language Architect, regarding how the `Optional` is intended to be used, and how it shouldn't be used from the perspective of its creators:

> Our intention was to provide a ***limited mechanism for library method return types*** where there needed to be a clear way to ***represent "no result"***, and using `null` for such was overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.
>
> For example, you probably should **never use** it for something that
> returns an **array** of results, or a **list** of results; instead return an
> **empty array** or **list**.

***Conclusion:*** design of the first API returning `Optional<List<Integer>>` is incorrect.

## Don't use Optional as an Argument

This considered a misuse of the Optional because it goes against the main design goal of Optional (see the quote above, also have a look at [*the answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/17949945) by *Stuart Marks*, Java and OpenJDK developer).

***Conclusion:*** design of the second API expecting `Optional<ArrayList<Integer>>` is also wrong.

## Write your code against Interfaces

Leverage abstractions, write your code against interfaces. There's no justification for making the code inflexible and capable only of consuming instances of `ArrayList` because it would not be able to deal with a `List` produced by `Collections.emptyList()`, `List.of()`, `Arrays.asList()`, `Stream.toList()`, etc.

See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

## Fixing the problem

Fix both endpoints if you can. Make them work without `Optional`.

In case if you're not in control of this first API returning the optional, fine, then don't make the problem bigger - fix the second API, make it expect a list of integer. And unpack the optional result right on the spot before call the second API.

You can use [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) for that purpose:

```
List<Integer> list = someAPI.call().orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

If you can't change both APIs, then you're out of luck.

Also, not that `listOne.map(ArrayList::new)` creates a **copy** of the initial data, that means that your system instead of making the second call immediately is forced to perform an additional step because of poor API design.

Comment: Agreed with you but API is written by someone else so I have no control over return type.

Comment: @DATATruejji That's unfortunate if you're not in control of both APIs. At least,  I've managed to deliver information regarding the best practices of using Optional that can useful to you in other situations, as well as to readers of this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with this:

```
Optional<List<Integer>> optionalList = getFromSomewhere();
```

You can convert to `Optional<ArrayList<Integer>>` like this:

```
Optional<ArrayList<Integer>> optionalArrayList
        = Optional.of(new ArrayList<>(optionalList.get()));
```

This is close to what you tried - `Optional.of(new ArrayList(listOne))` – but your attempt didn't work because `listOne` is type `Optional<List<Integer>>`, whereas [the constructor to `new ArrayList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) takes a Collection. If you call `.get()` then you'll get the list out of the Optional, and that works fine for the ArrayList constructor.

UPDATE: This is a safer way to do it, guarding empty optional. Agree that the other answer – `map(ArrayList::new)` – is a simpler, cleaner way to do it. In this answer, I wanted to address the approach initially taken by OP, how it was close and could be made to work.

```
if (list.isPresent()) {
    Optional<ArrayList<Integer>> optionalArrayList
        = Optional.of(new ArrayList<>(optionalList.get()));
}
```

Comment: also, `new ArrayList(listOne)` is raw.

Comment: This will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional` is empty. Probably better to use `map`, as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095669/6395627) shows.

Comment: @Slaw Good point. I added an edit to check the optional before calling get().

Comment: It's not the recommended way, it's overly complicated and it still does not take the empty `Optional` into account (it just does nothing in that case). I definitely recommend that no one tries to use this answer.