# How do I compare the minimum values in the list?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, option-type

I'm trying to compare the minimal values of two arrays.

I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.util.OptionalInt',
> 'java.util.OptionalInt'

What am I doing wrong?

*My code:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int [] ints = {12,6,8,242}; 

    int [] ints1 = {5,1,5432,5,76,146,8}; 

    if(Arrays.stream(ints).min()>Arrays.stream(ints1).min()){ 

        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(ints1).min()); 

    } 

}
```

Comment: `min()` returns `Optional<Integer>` not an `int`. What if one of your lists is empty? What is minimum value for an empty list?

Comment: @chptr-one It returns `OptionalInt` (`Arrays.stream(int[])` returns an `IntStream`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min()` retrieves `OptionalInt`. So to get a primitive `int` you have to call `getAsInt()`:

```java
int[] one = { 12, 6, 8, 242 };
int[] two = { 5, 1, 5432, 5, 76, 146, 8 };

if (Arrays.stream(one).min().getAsInt() > Arrays.stream(two).min().getAsInt())
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(two).min().getAsInt());
```

Another option is to use `Apache`:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;

int[] one = { 12, 6, 8, 242 };
int[] two = { 5, 1, 5432, 5, 76, 146, 8 };

if (NumberUtils.min(one) > NumberUtils.min(two))
    System.out.println(NumberUtils.min(two));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `min` returns an `OptionalInt`. This is beacuse calling `min` on an empty stream would be nonsensical (what int would it return?).

If you are certain your streams will *never* be empty, you can call `get` on the result of `min` to unwrap the optional and throw if it is empty. I would recommend specifying some behaviour in the case of an empty stream though. There are multiple methods on [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to make this easy to do. (`OptionalInt` has the same API as `Optional<T>` but wraps a primitive `int`)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can't compare two `Optional` objects using relational operators `<`, or `>` which are meant to be used only with primitive numbers.

In a nutshell, `Optional` - is a container of data, which might contain a resulting value or might not. Regardless of whether result is present, you can safely interact with this container, that's the core idea behind the Optional.

Optional API contain lots of methods for dialing with it. You can perform various manipulations with the optional (like transforming or filtering its value) **without** unpacking it. And when obtain the contained value `get()` (or `getAsInt()` in the case of `OptionalInt`) which is mentioned in another answer is the last option you should think of.

Here's a quote [*from the answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555) by Brian Goetz, Java Language Architect.

> **NEVER call** `Optional.get` **unless you can prove it will never be null**;
> instead use one of the safe methods like `orElse` or `ifPresent`. In
> retrospect, we should have called get something like
> `getOrElseThrowNoSuchElementException` or something that made it far
> clearer that this was a highly dangerous method that undermined the
> whole purpose of Optional in the first place. Lesson learned.
>
> **UPDATE:**
> Java 10 has `Optional.orElseThrow()`, which is semantically equivalent
> to `get()`, but whose name is more appropriate.

To perform an action on a result contained withing the Optional, API offers a method [`Optional.ifPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)), which expects a Consumer representing the action, which would be fired if the value is exists.

You can perform comparison of two values contained within Optionals, and print the first of them only both are present, and the first is greater than the second using the following approach:

```
int[] ints = {12, 6, 8, 242};
int[] ints1 = {5, 1, 5432, 5, 76, 146, 8};
    
getMin(ints).ifPresent(min1 -> getMin(ints1).ifPresent(min2 -> {
    if (min1 > min2) System.out.println(min1);
}));
```

To avoid repeating the same stream statement generating the optional result we can introduce a method:

```
public static OptionalInt getMin(int[] arr) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(arr).min();
}
```