# Guava - Collect values extracted from two Optionals into an ImmutableSet

Tags: java, set, option-type, guava, immutable-collections

I am looking to avoid multiple `if-else` conditions. Is there a more concise way of writing the below code?

```
private Set<String> getValues(Optional<String> one, Optional<String> two) {
    if (one.isPresent() && two.isPresent()) {
        return ImmutableSet.of(one.get(), two.get());
    } else if (one.isPresent()) {
        return ImmutableSet.of(one.get());
    } else {
        return two.isPresent() ? ImmutableSet.of(two.get()) : ImmutableSet.of();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the guava `ImmutableSet`, or are you using some other library?

Comment: yes , it is guava

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 11

Comment: Mind that Collector [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) gives **no** guarantees on mutability of the returned `Set`. The current implementation makes use `HashSet`. So the currently excepted answer didn't fully address the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use [Optional.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), jdk9+:

```
   private Set<String> getValuesJdk9(Optional<String> one, Optional<String> two) {
       return Stream.concat(one.stream(), two.stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }
```

You can read more [here](https://blog.frankel.ch/optional-stream/)

If You are using JDK8 still:

```
 private Set<String> getValuesJdk8(Optional<String> one, Optional<String> two) {
       return Stream.of(one, two)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }
```

And one extreme version, when You can pass any number of arguments

```
   private Set<String> getAllValues(Optional<String>... options) {
        return Arrays.stream(options).flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }
```

Comment: `Collectors.toSet()` -> `Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()`, JDK10+

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

According to the documentation Collector [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) (*used in another answer*) gives **no** guarantees on the mutability of the returned `Set`. Currently, it provides a **mutable** general purpose implementation - `HashSet`.

If you need an **Immutable** `Set` here are the options:

- There are several ways to generate an [*Unmodifiable Set*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) offered by JDK.
- And you can make use of the Guava's features that allow to produce `ImmutableSet` including `Collector` `ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()`.

## Challenging the Problem-statement

Firstly, it's a **discouraged** practice to pass around `Optional`s.

Here's quote from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555) by Brian Goetz, Java Language Architect, regurding the disign goals of `Optional`:

> Our intention was to provide a **limited mechanism** for **library
> method return types** where there needed to be a clear way to
> represent "no result", and using null for such was overwhelmingly
> likely to cause errors.
>
> For example, you probably should never use it for something that
> returns an array of results, or a list of results; instead return an
> empty array or list. You should almost **never use** it as a field of
> something or a **method parameter**.

Also see the answer by Stuart Marks, Java and OpenJDK developer [**Uses for Optional**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional/23464794#23464794).

A cleaner alternative to using `Optional` as method parameter passing around the `Optional` you can provide a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) of `Optional` and evaluate it inside your method.

Assuming you have methods `foo()` and `bar()` returning an `Optional`, then if you change the method signature to:

```
getValues(Supplier<Optional<T>> first, Supplier<Optional<T>> second)
```

Then you can invoke the method like that: `getValues(x::foo, y::bar)`

And instead of operating with two optionals the problem can be generified to:

*"Collect N values from non-empty Optionals into an ImmutableSet"*

## Guava's [`ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#toImmutableSet())

Since Guava release version `21.0` (*which requires JDK 8 as a minimum version*) you can use `Collector` returned by `ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()`.

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> Set<T> getValues(Supplier<Optional<T>>... suppliers) {

    return Arrays.stream(suppliers)
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
}
```

## Standard JDK [Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableSet())

And just for the purpose of completeness, here's a solution with no dependencies required.

Since Java 10 Collector `toUnmodifiableSet()` is available in the JDK.

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> Set<T> getValues(Supplier<Optional<T>>... suppliers) {

    return Arrays.stream(suppliers)
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
}
```