# How to make Jackson deserialize explicit null to Optional.EMPTY, but not to serialize empty Optional as null

Tags: java, json, jackson, option-type

Assuming I have a POJO like this:

```java
public static class Test {
  private Optional<String> something;
}
```

And a Jackson mapper like this:

```java
var OBJECT_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
  .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
  .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
  .build();
```

If I deserialize the JSON string `{"something": null}`, I get a `Test` object with `something=null`. Instead of that, I want to get a Test object with `something=Optional.EMPTY`.

My desired deserialization strategy for Optional is:

- null → not provided
- Optional.empty() → provided null
- Optional.of() → provided not null

The above can be achieved if I keep the default `serializationInclusion` (remove the `serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)` setting). This results in serializing everything and including nulls in the JSON string output, which is not what I want.

```java
Test test = new Test();
// This should serialize to {}, not {"something": null}

Test test2 = new Test();
test2.setSomething(Optional.EMPTY);
// This should also serialize to {}, not {"something": null}
```

TLTR: is there a way to separate the `serializationInclusion` separately for serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Did you try to use Include.NON_NULL. That way Optional logic would still work and null values wont be included into the serialized json. But if you want to separate options you can define 2 ObjectMapper`s, one for each purpose or change the config every time you use it

Comment: you seem to be doing something wrong: that is definitely bad idea to use `Optional` as object's field.

Comment: @Yury I tried the Include.NON_NULL as well, doesn't make any difference vs Include.NON_ABSENT. It looks like the OptionalDeserializer is never invoked if a field has null literal value.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Oracle seems to have different opinion: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html

Comment: @Yury btw yes, the 2 ObjectMappers is a solution I thought of and could work, however I want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @k.liakos that is not an "Oracle's opinion", you just found someone's misleading blogpost under oracle.com domain. [You should almost never use it as a field of something or a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/3426309)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Well you seem to be right. However they say "almost" never. I want to have a tri-state value for PATCH update, in order to differentiate between a value not been provided (=don't update the field) vs provided null (=clear the field's value). And Optional seems like a nice feat for the case (Javascript has undefined+null to separate this). I could have added a custom wrapper class, but I would have to rewrite all Serializers/Deserializers and handling for JSON.

Comment: another way to deal with it is to use objectMapper.readerForUpdating (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/reader-for-updating.html). That will only update/deserialize values coming in json, and you dont have to use Optional for fields.

Comment: When both cases should serialize to `{}`. How will the client be able to construct a payload that actually sends null as value?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom serializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var OBJECT_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
                .build();
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new Test(null)));
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new Test(Optional.empty())));
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new Test(Optional.of("jim"))));

        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{}", Test.class).toString());
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{\"something\":null}", Test.class).toString());
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{\"something\":\"jim\"}", Test.class).toString());
    }
}

class Test {
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyOptionalSerializer.class)
    private Optional<String> something;

    public Test() {}

    Test(Optional<String> something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public Optional<String> getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(Optional<String> something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "something=" + something +
                '}';
    }
}

class MyOptionalSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Optional<?>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Optional<?> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            if (value.isPresent()) {
                gen.writeObject(value.get());
            } else {
                gen.writeObject(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, your answer pointed me to think in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, and it was very simple, I just got stuck: I wasn't using `readValue` for Deserialization, but instead `convertValue`.

As the javadoc of `convertValue` mentions:

> This method is functionally similar to first serializing given value into JSON, and then binding JSON data into value of given type

So since the `serializationInclusion` was set to skip nulls on output, the field was being removed completely in the intermediate step.

Reproduction example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JacksonOptionalTest {
    @Test
    public void testOptional() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var OBJECT_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
                .build();

        System.out.println("writeValueAsString");
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new MyClass(null)));
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new MyClass(Optional.empty())));
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new MyClass(Optional.of("jim"))));

        System.out.println("\nreadValue");
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{}", MyClass.class).toString());
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{\"something\":null}", MyClass.class).toString());
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("{\"something\":\"jim\"}", MyClass.class).toString());


        final var map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("something", null);

        System.out.println("\nconvertValue");
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.convertValue(map, MyClass.class).toString());
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    private static class MyClass {
        @JsonProperty
        private Optional<String> something;
    }
}
```

If you run the above test, it prints the following:

```
writeValueAsString
{}
{}
{"something":"jim"}

readValue
JacksonOptionalTest.MyClass(something=null)
JacksonOptionalTest.MyClass(something=Optional.empty)
JacksonOptionalTest.MyClass(something=Optional[jim])

convertValue
JacksonOptionalTest.MyClass(something=null)
```

In the last test with `convertValue` we can see that instead of deserializing the value to `Optional.empty`, we got null, which is expected according to what  `convertValue` does.